# Punctuation in "or in other words"

Tags: punctuation, commas

In a [Math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/180246/17206), I used the sentence:

> “some two of these propositions are true and the third one is false”, or in other words, “exactly 2 of 3 propositions are true”

Here I used “or in other words” to rephrase a statement for better comprehension, but I didn’t use a comma after “or”. On the Net, I see people both using and omitting the comma in that phrase. What is the correct punctuation in the phrase “or in other words” and why?

Comment: The most common form would be to just ditch the redundant word *"or"* and replace it with a full stop. In other words, I think you're asking the wrong question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: What's the reason for that? Is it that a comma there would signify too little pause?

Comment: @Mr Reality: There must have been dozens if not *hundreds* of ELU questions asking about whether a comma is needed or not. To which my stock response is *If you would pause in **speech**, include a comma, otherwise don't.* But the concept of *Use a full stop for a **longer** pause* has never occurred to me. Be honest though, don't you think my comment above would look a little "odd" if I'd used a comma instead of a full stop after the *words* "full stop"? Those last 10 words represent a complete (multi-clause) statement all on their own; they *deserve* the status of "independent sentence"! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Right, but I asked because we can put a semicolon instead there (and in the one in your comment) too, can't we -- since it also is a full-stop mark and is used to separate independent clauses?.

Comment: @Mr Reality:  Sure. It only took a few seconds to find [this example](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22other+words%2C+you+are+the+driving+force%22) of a *semicolon* separator before **in other words** in Google Books. To my mind, the punctuation choice here is about as relevant to *real* (spoken) language as choice of font. But returning to my original point, I'd say the choice of whether or not to include the word ***or*** is far more significant in terms of *actual use of language*. And even *that's* largely just a matter of "stylistic preference" (but I'd definitely ditch it! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The comma after *words* needs to be complemented by one before *in* because *in other words* is an integral phrase interrupting the rest of the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Use a semicolon to join two independent clauses when the second clause begins with a conjunctive adverb (*however, therefore, moreover, furthermore, thus, meanwhile, nonetheless, otherwise*) or a transition (*in fact, for example, that is, for instance, in addition, in other words, on the other hand, even so*).

> Terrorism in the United States has become a recent concern; in fact, the concern for America's safety has led to an awareness of global terrorism.

http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/566/01/ Retrieved on Mar 11, 2013. 11:02 am

Answer (score 0):

'or in other words', is an integral expression therefore it's reasonable that the commas are placed before it and after it - 'something, or in other words, something else'.

It's true that for many this issue is a conundrum and we can find on the Net versions where there's a comma also after the 'or' - but when translating this into the language of formal logic, we can see it produces an inconsistency, breaks the logical flow.

It is also a widely used standard to simply divide the long sentence into two - 'something. In other words, something else', although in my opinion it is deprived of a certain oratorical charm it has when used in a long sentence.